# Parsing a string into tokens in D

Tags: parsing, d

I am trying to do some file I/O in D, and got stuck. I am trying to read in a data file and parse a string into various parameters of an object. I did see an example on stack overflow, but i didn't really understand what they were doing--but i am familiar with how to do it in Java and sort of familiar with how to parse strings in C++.

What i am trying to do is take a string `Country,Exports,Trade Balance,Year,Population,Geographical Area` and break it apart into separate strings by the commas.

here is what there is so far. I tried using chomp() as chomp(line, ",") but it didn't work. 4

```
import std.stdio;
import std.file;
import std.string;

void main(string[] args)
{
if (exists("source/data.txt")){
    File file = File("source/data.txt", "r");

    while (!file.eof()) 
    {
      string line = chomp(file.readln());
      writeln(line);
    }

} else {
    writeln("No such file here...");
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for [split](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_array.html#split) or [splitter](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_iteration.html#.splitter)